# How to locate a coordinate on a squircle?

Tags: geometry

I am solving a finite difference problem with a squircle as the boundary. I want to know how to locate a point on the squircle with equation $x^4 + y^4 = 1$. It has the centre $(0,0)$ and radius $1$.

I know for a circle any line from the centre to a point on the circle is the radius so to locate say, the x-coordinate of a point I would use Pythagoras theorem. How do I locate say, an $x$-coordinate of a point on a squircle?

[image]

Comment: How do you want to locate it?  For $y$ in $[-1,1]$ you have $x=\pm \sqrt[4]{1-y^4}$

Comment: Thanks Henry! I guess I was over thinking. Thanks again

Comment: To say radius $1$ you need to define radius.  On some definitions it might be $\sqrt[4]{2} \approx 1.1892$

Comment: $(x,y)=(\sqrt{\cos\alpha},\sqrt{\sin\alpha})$

Answer (score 2):

If you know $y$ then
$$
x = (1 - y^4)^{1/4} .
$$

If you know the angle $\theta$ of the "radius" $r$ then
$$
x = r \cos \theta
$$
where  $r$ is given by
$$
r  = \left(\frac{1}{\cos^4\theta + \sin^4\theta}\right)^{1/4}.
$$